# What is a Hilbertian stack?

Tags: automorphic-forms

In describing spectral decompositions of some $L^2$ spaces, Moeglin-Waldspurger (Spectral Decomposition and Eisenstein Series) keep using the term "Hilbertian stack" (e.g. the Corollary in V.3.14) but give no definition. What do they mean?

Comment: Probably synonym for "Hilbert direct integral" or similar.

Comment: by 'stack' they might mean 'field'. In French _champ_ is used for both words. See eg "Champs continus d'espaces hilbertiens et de C*-algèbres" vs "Champ algébrique"